# how to set image as icon in react

Tags: reactjs, icons

I'm trying to use an image from my assets as an icon within a  component. I currently have this code:

[image]

The issue I'm facing is that the icon prop expects an image path, but it's not displaying the image correctly. How can I correctly use the image from my assets as an icon in this context?"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.